# php class constant or class construct bug?

Tags: php, class, oop

I have two class, one extents another.

this is base class code:

**TestClassConst.php**

```php
 class TestClassConst
{
   const AUDIT_REJECT_REASON = [
    0 => LoanAuditConstants::AUTO_REJECT_REASON_KEYWORD['not_exist_key']
   ];

  public function __construct()
  {
  }
}
```

this is child class code:

**TestClassConstChild .php**

```php
class TestClassConstChild extends TestClassConst
{
    public function testEcho() {
       var_dump(2321312);
    }
}
```

when I use `testEcho()`, process is error, This is what I expected:
:
[image]

but when base class `construct` function adds a param (`$a`), example:

```php
 class TestClassConst
 {
  const AUDIT_REJECT_REASON = [
    0 => 
  LoanAuditConstants::AUTO_REJECT_REASON_KEYWORD['not_exist_key']
 ];

  public function __construct($a)
  {
  }
}
```

when I use `testEcho()`, The program is stuck in an infinite loop, until nginx

> error 502 Bad Gateway

I can't understand it.how can I understand it? is php bug? or Laravel bug?

My environment setup: is `php7.1`, `laravel5.5`

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the function `testEcho()`?

Comment: How are you instantiating methods? Create a [mcve] for us.

Comment: $aa = new TestClassConstChild();
        var_dump($aa->testEcho());

Answer (score 0):

Since `TestClassConstChild` doesn't have a constructor of it's own, it inherits it's parent's constructor.

The parent constructor requires parameters. If you don't provide them, the script dies with a `Fatal error: Too few arguments` before it even gets to the part where you expect to get a undefined index warning.

I don't know how your Laravel is set up but if is hosting itself it means the server is dying and `nginx` is simply reporting the fact.

Comment: I think it is laravel bug, but I can't find the reason now.